Implementing natural boundary conditions for the heat conductivity of a rod
I'm facing the following problem regarding the heat conductivity of a rod, $t: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$-(c(x)t'(x))'=h(x),$
$t(0)=0,$
$c(1)t'(1)=d$
With $x \in (0,1)$, $d \in R$, $c(x)$ and $h(x)$ being arbitrary functions of $x$.
In particular, I'm struggling with how to implement the natural boundary condition (not so much the Dirichlet at $x = 0$).
My first step was setting up my space of test functions,
$V = [ v: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \int_{0}^{1} (v(x)^2 + v'(x)^2) \, dx < \infty,  v(0) = 0, v(1) = 1 ] $
Then I multiplied my equation by a test function $v \in V$ and after some partial integrations, I got
$\int_{0}^{1} c(x) t'(x) v'(x) dx - c(1) t'(1) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) v(x) dx$
What do I do with the c(1) t'(1) term? When I've set up the matrix system with conductivity matrix $A$, coefficient vector $\psi$, and right hand side functional vector $L$:
$A \psi = L$
Do I just add $d$ to the last element in $t$? I'm using one-point gaussian quadrature and hat functions for the elements, but regardless of that information I have no clue what to do with the c(1) t'(1) term.
Regards, Nomi.
PS: The condition t(0) = 0 doesn't do anything here correct? I just dismiss it.

The only change to make is to use the same space, but without the zero boundary condition at $x=1$. Then the right hand side of your problem has the additional term $d(v(1))$ which comes from $c(1)t'(1)v(1)=dv(1)$.
